# How to fix the Windows 7 UDP reply to Linux UDP connection creator? Where Linux to Linux works but Linux to Windows 7 not working

Tags: java, linux, sockets, windows-7, udp

The PC Windows is sending the confirmation. But that is not arriving to Linux. 
What am i missing? (But when i do not use Windows 7 and do the same code under Linux to Linux it works.)

Any ideas!!!

## Windows 7 PC: Sender/Replyer

```
System.out.println("[UDP]: " 
          + "RemoteIP: " + IPAddress.toString() + " "
          + "Port: " + port + " " 
          + "Length: " + send.length() + " "
          + "Sending confirmation!"); // it shows it has correct ip, port and lenght                   
sockOutput = new DatagramPacket(send.getBytes(), send.length(), IPAddress, port);
serverSock.send(sockOutput);// is it failing???
```

## Linux PC: Receiver/Commander

```
String receive = sendUDPBytes("request", ip).toString();

if (receive.length()<=0) // Waiting forever, and nothing happens LINUX.
{
    System.out.println("FAILED");
    System.exit(0);
} else {
      try {                                          
            /* JOB todo */
      } catch (Exception ex) {

      }                    
}
sockOutput.write(receive.getBytes());

public static String sendUDPBytes(String bytes, String[] ip) throws IOException
{            
    String downloaded = null;      
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip[2]);

    byte[] sendData = new byte[14024];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[14024];

    sendData = bytes.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length);
    socket.connect(IPAddress, 58889);
    if (socket.isConnected())
    {
        System.out.println("[UDP]: sending....., waiting......... until receive....");
        socket.send(sendPacket);
    }

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);      
    downloaded = new String(receivePacket.getData());

    System.out.println("[UDP]: closing.....");
    socket.close();              
    return downloaded;
}
```

**Follow up:**

0) Do not get confuse with "ARE U IN A SAME SUBSET???", so if you have /28 network all in can exchange the packet. In that case it works but that is not the case most of the time.

1) The code is perfect, when i test LAN to LAN no matter what operating system it is, it works (no firewall ofcource)

2) When i test Windows to Windows in the same PC it works too

3) When i test Linux to Linux it works too

4) When i test Linux to Windows or Windows to Linux it works too

5) The same code i put in one central server and same code i ran in local Windows PC, and  other ISP seems to allow it.

6) Sp-ended 10 hours to find it

Guess:

What exactly was then the cause? Well, ISP is losing the packet that was sent to my public IP or they maybe disabling those even i have Public IP.

Comment: Is your windows firewall turned off? Can you run the sender/receiver on the same window box?

Comment: Keep in mind that UDP is not reliable.

Comment: @ckuetbach, *not reliable* is not the same thing as *systematically drops the packets on the floor*, though.

Comment: Are your Windows and Linux machines on the same subnet? Please post their IP addresses (you can change a high order bit to protect the innocent), and subnet masks.

Comment: Run wireshark on both machines, set a filter for the address and ports you're using. What do the logs show?

Comment: Yes it working, i put wireshark and manually traced them where is the Windows 7 packet was going. I called ISP to find it and then i called my Windows 7 PC ISP suppliers, to find where is my packet going. Finally found it where it is going nowhere, its lost in ISP. And they are doing wrong maybe newcomer networking engineers they got. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `String bytes` and `getBytes()` depends on the platform encoding. `getBytes("UTF-8")` would be explicit.

Another thing are the differing newlines: Linux \n, Windows \r\n.

The `toString()` might throw an exception if the bytes stem from Windows Latin-1 (Cp1252), and it tries to interprete them as UTF-8.

---

```
private void test(OutputStream sockOutput, String[] ip) throws IOException {
    String receive = sendUDPBytes("request", ip);

    if (receive.length() <= 0) // Waiting forever, and nothing happens LINUX.
    {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        try {
            /*
             * JOB todo
             */
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    sockOutput.write(receive.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

public static String sendUDPBytes(String bytes, String[] ip) throws IOException {
    return new String(sendUDPBytesRaw(bytes.getBytes("UTF-8"), ip), "UTF-8");
}

public static byte[] sendUDPBytesRaw(byte[] sendData, String[] ip) throws IOException {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip[2]);

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[14024];

    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length);
    socket.connect(IPAddress, 58889);
    if (socket.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println("[UDP]: sending....., waiting......... until receive....");
        socket.send(sendPacket);
    }

    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    socket.receive(receivePacket);
    byte[] downloaded = receivePacket.getData();

    System.out.println("[UDP]: closing.....");
    socket.close();
    return downloaded;
}
```

Comment: @Google I start to believe you are right, especially with the pure ASCII you sent, but I still edited my answer with `byte[]`, so you could give it a try if noone answers.

Comment: To remove, avoid confusion. Please see my edit. Its working exactly how my code was, and also your sample. It was just my ISP who blocks my public ip UDP random port opening which is indeed Dagagram.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I could not see anything wrong, port > 1000, no firewalls.